# is there a way simillar to this way to save files (.docx, pdf...) in django?

Tags: python, django

I've been lately wondering how to save file for each user using django , i kinda thought about this way:

the html page:

```
 <form acrion ="{% url 'register'%}">
   name: <input type="text" name ="name">
    resume: <input type="file" name ="myfile">
    <input type="button" value="signup">
    </form>
```

the modes.py file:

```
class someOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    resume = models.FielField(upload_to="wherever i want")
```

the views.py file

```
 def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST['name']
            resume = request.POST['resume']

        new_user = someOne(name,resume)

        new_user.save()
```

is there anyway should be easy like this or i need to search another way hope you guys **undrestand** me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can do that. but you have to make little changes in your code.

add enctype to multipart form data in your html form like `<form acrion ="{% url 'register'%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and use request.FILES for getting file in your view.

You can use this decent tutorial for your reference : 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/

Comment: you mean request.FILES['myflie'] my input name "myfile" is that cool ?